# Pure java class not behaving same in android than in a PC

Tags: java, android, encryption

Here is the complete class (it is a wrapper for an AES Encryption and Decryption)

```
package encryptiondebug;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * Created by ariela on 12/29/17.
 */

public class AESEngine {

    public class AESReturn {
        int retCode;
        String lastError;
        String data;
    }

    public static final int AES_OK              = 1;
    public static final int AES_KEY_GEN_ERROR   = 3;
    public static final int AES_KEY_ENGINE_INIT = 2;
    public static final int AES_ENCRYPT_ERROR   = 4;
    public static final int AES_WRITE_ERROR     = 5;
    public static final int AES_READ_ERROR      = 6;
    public static final int AES_DECRYPT_ERROR   = 7;
    public static final int AES_CANNOT_MAKE_DIR = 8;

    // Aux.
    private final static String ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    private final static String ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private final static int NCHARS = 16;

    // Private variables
    private byte[] rawdata;
    private byte[] keyBytes;

    // AES Variables
    private static Cipher cipher;
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;
    private static IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;

    public AESEngine (){

    }

    public AESReturn getEmptyReturn(){
        AESReturn r = new AESReturn();
        r.data = "";
        r.lastError = "";
        r.retCode = AES_OK;
        return r;
    }

    public AESReturn initEngine(String passwd){

        AESReturn r = getEmptyReturn();

        // Initializing variables.
        rawdata = null;

        // Transforming the passwd to 16 bytes.
        try {
            MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(Charset.forName(ENCODING).encode(passwd).array());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[NCHARS];
            int byteCount;
            while ((byteCount = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                digester.update(buffer, 0, byteCount);
            }
            keyBytes = digester.digest();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            r.lastError = e.toString();
            r.retCode = AES_KEY_GEN_ERROR;
            return r;
        }

        // Initializing the crypto engine
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            r.lastError = e.toString();
            r.retCode = AES_KEY_ENGINE_INIT;
            return r;
        }
        secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);

        return r;

    }


    //====================== AES Encryption ======================
    public AESReturn encrypt(String plaintext,String dataFile){

        AESReturn r = getEmptyReturn();

        try{
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            rawdata = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF8"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            r.lastError = e.toString();
            r.retCode = AES_ENCRYPT_ERROR;
            return r;
        }


        // Writing the file with encrypted data.
        try{
            DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile));

            // This way the first four bytes represent the length of the written data.
            fos.writeInt((int)rawdata.length);
            fos.write(rawdata,0,rawdata.length);
            fos.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            r.lastError = e.toString();
            r.retCode =  AES_WRITE_ERROR;
            return r;
        }
        return r;
    }

    //====================== AES Decryption ======================
    public AESReturn decrypt(String dataFile){

        AESReturn r = getEmptyReturn();

        // Opening the file for reading
        byte[] eBytes = null;
        try{
            DataInputStream fis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(dataFile));

            // Reading the size of the written files
            int size = fis.readInt();

            // Reading the rest of the file
            eBytes = new byte[size];
            fis.readFully(eBytes);
            fis.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            r.retCode = AES_READ_ERROR;
            r.lastError = e.toString();
            return r;
        }


        // The data is read and now we attempt to decrypted.
        try{
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            rawdata = cipher.doFinal(eBytes);
            r.data = new String(rawdata,ENCODING);
        }
        catch(InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            r.retCode = AES_DECRYPT_ERROR;
            r.lastError = e.toString();
            return  r;
        }

        return r;
    }

}
```

The way I call this class in my PC app is like thiss:

```
    AESEngine aesEngine = new AESEngine();
    AESEngine.AESReturn aer = aesEngine.initEngine(password);
    if (aer.retCode != AESEngine.AES_OK){
        System.err.println("Error INIT. Code: " + aer.lastError);
        return;
    }        

    aer = aesEngine.decrypt(filepath);
    if (aer.retCode != AESEngine.AES_OK) {
        System.err.println("Decrypt error: " + aer.lastError);
        return;            
    }

    System.err.println("Decrypted data:");
    System.err.println(aer.data);
```

The class (which is the same) is called in the same way on Android. On android the file is decrypted correctly but on PC I get this error:

```
Decrypt error: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

The only way that I can think that this is possible is because the Java class has changed. I'm sure that the file is the same and that the password is correct (as it decrypts without any issues on my phone).

Any ideas?

**CLARIFICATION:** When I say it does not work on PC: I mean that I imported the same classs, changed the packet name, and used Netbeans to run a program in the PC to run the code above.

EDIT:

This is the result of a new test where I enctrypted to a file and then decrypted:

```
    AESEngine aesEngine = new AESEngine();
    AESEngine.AESReturn aer = aesEngine.initEngine(password);
    if (aer.retCode != AESEngine.AES_OK){
        System.err.println("Error INIT. Code: " + aer.lastError);
        return;
    }        

    aer = aesEngine.encrypt("This is my world", outpath);
    if (aer.retCode != AESEngine.AES_OK) {
        System.err.println("Decrypt error: " + aer.lastError); 
    }
    else{
        System.err.println("Encryption sucessfull");
    }

    aer = aesEngine.decrypt(outpath);
    if (aer.retCode != AESEngine.AES_OK) {
        System.err.println("Decrypt error: " + aer.lastError);
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Decrypted data:");
        System.err.println(aer.data);
    }
```

This worked as expected:

```
Encryption sucessfull
Decrypted data:
This is my world
```

EDIT 2: It has been pointed out that the question here is same as [Why am I getting 'BadPaddingException' when decrypting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806764/why-am-i-getting-badpaddingexception-when-decrypting). However, first my code works on android and does not work on PC. Second I can encrypt and decrypt the message on PC without issues. Third the fact that the code works on Android guarantees that I'm not messing up the password.

Comment: There was somthing about not using flush and close. I do use close and use the readFully fucntion which should read everything. Where would flush be used?

Comment: When you say PC, you mean an emulator?

Comment: No. I mean I litterally imported the class, created a new project in Netbeans and run the program. The only difference between the code running in my phone and my pc is the package name at top. I litterally copied and pasted the file AESEngine.java.